# Draw On Screen Live

Tags: xorg

I'd like to have functionality like [this](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/draw-diagrams-pictures-presentations-sketch/) in Linux, Xorg, whereby I can sketch on the desktop as in the example image below. Anybody have suggestions?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use [**Gromit-MPX**](https://github.com/bk138/gromit-mpx#readme), which is an improved version of [Gromit](http://www.home.unix-ag.org/simon/gromit/). Since it allows (but not requires) compositing, it should be much faster than Gromit where a compositing X11 desktop is available.

It's available in the Debian / Ubuntu repos at least. See [my related answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/690802) over at askubuntu.com StackExchange for installation and usage under Ubuntu. (Usage in short: use <kbd>Pause</kbd> instead of <kbd>F9</kbd> under Ubuntu.)

Comment: In 2018, this is what I use.

Comment: And again in 2022.

Answer (score 7):

It seems such a tool exists for GNU/Linux already. It's called Ardesia. Read about it [here](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2010/09/ardesia-touchscreen-drawing-app-linux)

Example (taken from the above link):

[image]

Also, note that `ardesia` seems to have made its way into the repos (it's in the Debian stable repos, at least).

Comment: Seems to be awesome, except I need to install a compositor. For Fluxbox, maybe I'll just go Compiz and be done with it! Thanks!

Comment: @T.C. If you're going with Compiz, you should also consider its Annotate plugin suggested in slm's answer.

Answer (score 6):

#### Pylote

Here's another one, [Pylote](http://pascal.peter.free.fr/wiki/Logiciels/Pylote#en). It's a Python based app.

[image: ss of pylote]

#### Compiz Annotate Plugin

There's also this plugin to Compiz, simply called [Annotate](http://wiki.compiz.org/Plugins/Annotate).

#### Gromit

This is another option, which is in the repos, at least on Ubuntu. It's called [Gromit](http://www.home.unix-ag.org/simon/gromit/).

[image: gromit]

Comment: @JosephR. - yeah, you'll have to download and install this one the old fashioned way 8-)