# A program to draw on screen in X11

Tags: arch-linux, x11, software-rec, dwm

I'm using dwm on Arch Linux.
Is there an existing program I can use to draw on the screen? For example, if I'm in a zoom meeting, sharing my screen, I'd like to scribble over the code I'm showing in vim, or math in a pdf document.

I saw `ardesia` recommended [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/102835/116187), but it requires a compositor. And even if I run `picom`, the toolbar from `ardesia` appears, but if I try to draw, the drawing doesn't appear on the screen, and if I type, the text has weird artifacts and disappears as soon as I try drawing something.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because product recommendations are generally considered off topic on SO

Comment: The `software-rec` tag is for "recommendations for software for a particular purpose".

Answer (score 0):

Why not use a whiteboard (e.g. https://github.com/cracker0dks/whiteboard)  this allows other people to draw on it too - and just apply images of the stuff you want to share.